# .htaccess file configuration for public section of my website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to deploy my site online and the `.htaccess` file which worked perfectly in the `localhost` seem not be be working the same way on my share hosting domain.

i have a `public` folder in the root(htdocs) folder which is meant to serve the public files and I used two `.htaccess` files one in the public directory and the other in the the root(`htdocs`) folder.

.htaccess for htdocs folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.morehere\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.morehere\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

and that of the public directory

```
# --- Homepage
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php [NC,L]

# --- articles page
RewriteRule ^articles $ articles.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles /$ articles.php [NC]
........
```

My intention is to make the URLs search engine friendly and appealing to users.

Edit: I have made sure `mod_rewrite` on the production server is turns on but the pages still gets redirected to the not found page.

Like `mysite.morehere.net/home/` is redirected to the not found page

Can anyone please help me out to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You probably have never heard about thing called **Front Controller**. You'd better learn about it before you start writing the application

Comment: Can you show full code of `/public/.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes! I copied the code in the htdocs `.htaccess` file to public .htaccess file and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if mod_rewrite is turned on, on your production server